# InputStream returns libcore.net.http.fixedlengthinputstream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I don't know what `libcore.net.http.fixedlengthinputstream` means and how can I solve it to get the actual string. Please help me out. Below is my code.

```
private void fetchHomeScreenData() {
    Log.wtf("SidePlease", "inside fetch...");  
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    URL url = new URL(AppConstants.homeUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                    Log.wtf("SP", is.toString());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.wtf("SidePlease", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }).start();

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SidePlease.this);
        alert.setTitle("SidePlease").setMessage("You are currently not connected to the intenet. Please check your network setting and try again.")
        .setNeutralButton("Okay", null).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: See [http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-the-content-from-a-httpresponse-or-any-inputstream-as-a-string ] (Get String from inputstream)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, the snippet is not correct. It swallows the line-feeds.